# Converter string para json [Python]

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, conversão-de-tipo, conversão

estou com um caso onde tenho um json(está como clob) no banco e quero usar ele para fazer uma requisição post e tudo pelo python, mas estou com um problema no momento de converter essa string para json. O que acontece é que todas as " são transformadas em ' e isso está dando problema na requisição, pois ele acaba entendendo que os atributos do meu objeto "pai" são na verdade valores dele.

Ex:
Valor original:

```
{
    "contrato": {
        "atb1": "013128415879",
        "atb2": "20200109",
        "atb3": 0,
        "obj1": {
            "atb4": "182938",
            "atb5": "ABCD",
            "atb6": 3
        },
        "obj2": {
            "atb7": "100104353",
            "atb8": 25
        }
    }
}
```

Valor após a conversão(json.loads):

```
{
    'contrato': {
        'atb1': '013128415879', 
        'atb2': '20200109', 
        'atb3': 0, 
        'obj1': {
            'atb4': '182938', 
            'atb5': 'ABCD', 
            'atb6': 3
            }, 
        'obj2': {
            'atb7': '100104353', 
            'atb8': 25
        }
    }
}
```

E essa estrutura chega pra no meu serviço da seguinte forma:

```
{
    'contrato': [
        'atb1',
        'atb2',
        'atb3',
        'obj1',
        'obj2'
    ]
}
```

Sabem me dizer o que posso fazer para meu serviço receber o json de forma correta? Estou usando as bibliotecas "requests" e "json".

A parte do código onde trato o valor:

```
payload = str(result[3])#no result está uma linha do banco
payload = json.loads(payload) #aqui é onde faço a conversão para json
```

Answer (score 0):

Dado que vc confia na fonte da informação (**a string que contem o json sempre está correta**), pode usar isso:

```
import json
import requests

json_string = """{
    "contrato": {
        "atb1": "013128415879",
        "atb2": "20200109",
        "atb3": 0,
        "obj1": {
            "atb4": "182938",
            "atb5": "ABCD",
            "atb6": 3
        },
        "obj2": {
            "atb7": "100104353",
            "atb8": 25
        }
    }
}"""


j = eval(json_string)
r = requests.post('www.url_to_send.com', json=j)
```

Comment: Consegui resolver mudando uma informação na requisição, antes eu estava passando como "data" depois da URL ao invés de "json" conforme seu exemplo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Fico feliz de ter ajudado.:-)